# SOAP function call not getting executed

Tags: php, soap

I have a code like

```
$data = $soapClient->__soapCall($method, $parameters, $options, $headers, $outputHeaders);
```

My code breaks here, by giving error like

```
[Thu 07 26 15:53:42 2012]   exception:Critical  SoapClient->__doRequest@145 /www/soaps/index    A SoapFault has occured: Gone
```

I am trying to access URL :`http://soap.amazon.com/schemas3/AmazonWebServices.wsdl` using function `KeywordSearchRequest`. `__soapCall` is breaking but `__getFunctions` is working properly. How do i solve this issue or what wrong i am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to access the Web-service, I got the response. May be you need to upgrade/change the WebService.

We're Sorry

### We're Sorry - Service Gone

Amazon Ecommerce Web Service 3.0 has been deprecated after many years of useful service on March 31st 2008. Please upgrade to the Amazon Associates Web Service 4.0 as detailed in the [migration guide](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?categoryID=12&externalID=627). Please visit [Amazon Associates Web Service Developer Forum](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forum.jspa?forumID=9&start=0) for more information.  If you came to this page from an RSS feed, visit [Amazon's Product RSS Feeds](http://www.amazon.com/b/?ie=UTF8&node=390052011) page for an upgrade.

Comment: can u tell me any proper SOAP. web service which i can test with. Because i am writing a module to consume SOAP service data. Please check if u get error for link http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?wsdl also

Comment: No, This web service is working fine for me. I can access many functions like AllGames, Cities, etc.

Comment: Did u use any parameters along with it ?